# Python virtualenv forgets to use Python 3?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, virtualenv

I've created a Python3 virtualenv as follows:

```
virtualenv -p python3 mysite.org
source mysite.org/bin/activate
```

This works fine for a bit:

```
(mysite.org)$ which python
/Users/me/Dropbox/mysite.org/mysite.org/bin/python
(mysite.org)$ python -v
Python 3.4.2 (default, Jan 29 2015, 13:46:46)
```

But then suddenly, while still inside the virtualenv, it will "forgot" to use Python 3 and start using system Python:

```
(mysite.org)$ which python
/usr/bin/python
(mysite.org)$ python -v
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36)
```

Why might this happen, and how can I fix it? Currently I have to delete and re-create the virtualenv, which is tedious.

I haven't been able to identify any specific behaviour that causes this to happen. I'm using OSX Yosemite.

Comment: Sounds like a shell profile or something deactivating it, my guess is that the `path_helper` is causing issues, try this to check: `sudo chmod ugo-x /usr/libexec/path_helper
`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: the python 2.7.6 in that picture is the yosemite default python, the date refers to the python build date.

Comment: Have you tried deactivating and reactivating the env? I would print out your `PATH` variable before and after it "forgets", my guess is some other script is re-inserting `/usr/bin` before your virtualenv bin. Maybe `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` getting re-run somehow?

Comment: try: which -a python

Answer (score 0):

To my best knowledge virtualenv works by setting your PATH environment. Something is resetting the PATH variable